# regular expression to only allow numbers, numbers with dot, & and space

Tags: regex

I'm going to need a regular expression that only allows numbers, spaces, decimal numbers with precision of 2, and & sign.

This regular expression will be used to check for an input that allows multiple numbers separated by & sign, and there can be space (optional, but maximum one) in between. The following is what I've tried, due to my poor understanding in regex, they worked so poorly.

```
^(?=.*[0-9])[ &.0-9]+$
```

but it doesn't work well.

because things like &&&&&&1 will pass the check.

have also tried things like this, which also works so poorly

```
^([0-9]{1,}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}[ ]{0,1}+[&]{0,1}[ ]{0,1})*?$
```

The following exemplifies what I expected

12 ---> (pass)

12.12 ---> (pass)

12 & 129.12 & 11 --- >(pass)

12 & 129. & 11 ---> (should not pass)

12 & .129 ---> (should not pass)

12 & 129..1 (should not pass)

12 & 129.111 (should not pass)

&&&1 (should not pass)

.......

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To account for the spaces, you might make them optional using `?`

You might use a repeating pattern matching 2 optional spaces and an ampersand:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?(?: ?& ?\d+(?:\.\d{2})?)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+(?:\.\d{2})?` Match 1+ digits and optionally match a dot and 2 digits
- `(?:` Non capturing groupo

  - `[ ]?&[ ]?` Match an optional space (used `[ ]` for clarity), `&` and optional space
  - `d+(?:\.\d{2})?` Match 1+ digits and optionally match a dot and 2 digits
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times to also allow a single entry
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nv9nmx/1)

Comment: @JohnyL That is due to the formatting. Let me update it.